# The paralelogram law and the polarisation identity

Tags: geometry, functional-analysis

I am struggling to remember the parallelogram law and the polarisation identity. Every time I need one of the two I have to look them up both. Therefore I would like to better understand the two so that I can remember them and don't have to look them up anymore.

What I know:

One of the two can be used to determine whether a given norm is induced by an inner product. This is extremely useful.

The parallelogram law states:

$$ 2 \|x\|^2 + 2\|y\|^2 = \|x + y \|^2 + \|x - y\|^2 $$

This is kind of like Pytagoras' theorem: $x^2+y^2=(x+y)^2$ if $x \bot y$. But in a parallelogram, $x \not\bot y$. In words this says that the sum of the squares of the lengths of the sides of a parallelogram equals the sum of the squares of the lenghts of the diagonals.

> What does the sums of the sides of a parallelogram have
>   to do with (the existence of) an inner product?

The polarisation identity states:

$$ \langle x,y \rangle = {1 \over 4}(\|x+y\|^2 - \|x-y\|^2)$$

Which expresses the inner product in terms of the norm.

But I think I don't really understand the two identities.

> How should I think of them in order to better understand? Is there any
>   geometric meaning that helps remember each, relate them and tell them apart?

Comment: Note that your polarization identity only holds for real inner product spaces. For complex ones, you have $$ \langle x,y\rangle = \frac{1}{4} \sum_{j=1}^4 i^4 \langle x+i^4 y, x+i^4 y\rangle.$$

Comment: After you expand out $\|x\pm y\|^{2}$ using inner product a dozen times or so to see that adding the two cancels out inner product terms, and subtracting cancels out the norms, then you'll remember it. Finding an identity that (a) characterizes geometry (b) doesn't involve inner products couldn't have been easy. Use of the parallelogram does that. Don't know about you, but I didn't know about that identity until I started studying inner product spaces. I still find it remarkable that a simple norm identity can characterize a space where you have Pythagorean geometry and orthogonality.

Comment: @PhoemueX: Muscle memory: I think you have to many fours within the polarization identity... ^^

Comment: @Freeze_S: You are correct :) What I meant to write was of course $$\langle x, y\rangle = \frac{1}{4} \sum_{j=1}^4 i^j \langle x+i^j y , x + i^j y\rangle.$$ Thanks for the correction.$$ $$ For the **geometric meaning** of the parallelogram law, see this Wikipedia entry http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law#The_parallelogram_law_in_inner_product_spaces, in particular the graphics! It is called parallelogram identity, because it says something about the length of the sides of a parallelogram.